# Project Id in error message is not the one set in `gcloud config set` when use Google API Client Library

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I call the Storage Transfer API following the documentation.
https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/transferJobs/patch

This is my code.

```
from pprint import pprint
from googleapiclient import discovery
import google.auth
credentials, project = google.auth.default()

service = discovery.build("storagetransfer", "v1", credentials=credentials)
job_name = "transferJobs/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

update_transfer_job_request_body = {
    "transferJob": {"description": "xxxxxxxxxxx"},
    "projectId": project,
}

request = service.transferJobs().patch(
    jobName=job_name, body=update_transfer_job_request_body
)
response = request.execute()

pprint(response)
```

Before executing this script, I ran the `gcloud config list` to make sure the project id was correct and that the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` was not set.

But I see another project id(aaaaaaaaaaa) in the next returned error message.

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://storagetransfer.googleapis.com/v1/transferJobs/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?alt=json returned "Caller does not have required permission to use project aaaaaaaaaaa. Grant the caller the roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer role, or a custom role with the serviceusage.services.use permission, by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=aaaaaaaaaaa and then retry. Propagation of the new permission may take a few minutes.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help', 'links': [{'description': 'Google developer console IAM admin', 'url': 'https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=aaaaaaaaaaa'}]}, {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'USER_PROJECT_DENIED', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'service': 'storagetransfer.googleapis.com', 'consumer': 'projects/aaaaaaaaaaa'}}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume Project ID `aaaaaaaaaaa`does not correspond to the ID of one your projects.

I'm not on a device where I can easily use `gcloud` but, when I get to one, I'll add the Project ID used by `gcloud` to synthesize Service Accounts from user accounts with `gcloud auth application-default` credentials.

I think you should *not* use `gcloud auth application-default` credentials but should create a Service Account in your project, grant it suitable permissions and authenticate with it .

If your code is running off GCP, you'll need to `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/key` before running the code.

Using `gcloud auth application-default` can be useful for testing code but it's increasingly discouraged in favor of using a proper Service Account. One problem with it is that the synthetic Service Account is owned by a Google-owned project (`aaaaaaaaaaa`) not a user-owned project and the Google-owned project does not have every Google API enabled.

I think this is the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: You are right. In most cases, it is more appropriate to use Service Account. I'm just curious why I see other project id in the error message.You mentioned `gcloud auth application-default` and let me know that Application Default Credentials are saved `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`. The file have the Project ID (aaaaaaaaaaaaaa).

Answer (score 0):

As @DazWilkin said using a service account will be more appropriate, In addition to this by adding the  Cloud IAM permission `serviceusage.services.enable` to enable services. Depending on what features you require, such as listing services, you need `serviceusage.services.list` can resolve the error.

Typically you can add the role `roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageAdmin` which includes the following permissions:

- serviceusage.services.get
- serviceusage.services.list
- serviceusage.services.enable
- serviceusage.services.disable

Refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/access-control) for more information on Service Usage uses IAM to control access to services and Refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#grant-single-role) for adding roles to a service account.